# ./startFabric.sh failed; fabric-couchdb failed to start

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I followed the [Hyperledger Composer installation guide for the development environment.](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) The development environment is set up inside a Linux container (LXD) running ubuntu 16.04.

When I want to start the Network I'm facing the following error:

```
ubuntu@hyperledger ~/fabric-dev-servers % ./startFabric.sh 
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'startFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
Removing network composer_default
WARNING: Network composer_default not found.
Creating network "composer_default" with the default driver
Pulling ca.org1.example.com (hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0)...
x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-ca
1be7f2b886e8: Pull complete
6fbc4a21b806: Pull complete
c71a6f8e1378: Pull complete
4be3072e5a37: Pull complete
06c6d2f59700: Pull complete
4d536120d8a5: Pull complete
0baaf9ec263e: Pull complete
ab27f0b1192c: Pull complete
7e1142a727eb: Pull complete
a7624c188c44: Pull complete
0c8524afd242: Pull complete
23e14758f709: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:92f44d0811cddb0d335f7879f7e3b3c4b631f31740c76f3e7b85438c244b03f4
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0
Pulling couchdb (hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6)...
x86_64-0.4.6: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
8f7c85c2269a: Pull complete
9e72e494a6dd: Pull complete
3009ec50c887: Pull complete
9d5ffccbec91: Pull complete
e872a2642ce1: Pull complete
9b84958a26b3: Pull complete
68d4ced7ec19: Pull complete
ff1d2b44d88d: Pull complete
99e6a41c35bd: Pull complete
87b2e4a0b9d2: Pull complete
55f108d3ee4a: Pull complete
9e76f6c2c001: Pull complete
368be4b23f81: Pull complete
581042703e1f: Pull complete
18c50435ee69: Pull complete
70dbffc27ecb: Pull complete
31c35dd1bd00: Pull complete
7571e6af230f: Pull complete
9ef1e88f8344: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4278269b115cfd0f24251b5381407be9ccdf396c1470c69e1ee2ff16917ac882
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6
Pulling orderer.example.com (hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0)...
x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-orderer
1be7f2b886e8: Already exists
6fbc4a21b806: Already exists
c71a6f8e1378: Already exists
4be3072e5a37: Already exists
06c6d2f59700: Already exists
4d536120d8a5: Already exists
0baaf9ec263e: Already exists
770563795186: Pull complete
61d33418a569: Pull complete
b1b98004e7c6: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0c3a3b5ecfd24b513da22bbb77da7b3f5bca9c121cc0ac5c46ba04c97c163654
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0
Pulling peer0.org1.example.com (hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0)...
x86_64-1.1.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-peer
1be7f2b886e8: Already exists
6fbc4a21b806: Already exists
c71a6f8e1378: Already exists
4be3072e5a37: Already exists
06c6d2f59700: Already exists
4d536120d8a5: Already exists
0baaf9ec263e: Already exists
770563795186: Already exists
15763b7bd14b: Pull complete
62f2823da7f3: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:57417699ddf50c5ebd47a9a2cc74c0324fbba0281eb1104b9ddd05a67776b01f
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
Creating ca.org1.example.com ... 
Creating couchdb ... 
Creating orderer.example.com ... 
Creating couchdb
Creating orderer.example.com
Creating couchdb ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... 
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
sleeping for 15 seconds to wait for fabric to complete start up
2018-07-16 14:47:20.745 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.745 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.746 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 006 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 007 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0AA2060A074F7267314D53501296062D...6D706F736572436F6E736F727469756D 
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: 1D0ED42E07D2F3C749FC1727D62017AB69EC4C9B75CDA40C7A38BAD6A76B2EA4 
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0ADF060A1B08021A0608F8DFB2DA0522...91AB9023E7372FF4B9B101C772D0B8DD 
2018-07-16 14:47:20.752 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: C694AA5DD7585E93A385201864C0E8A6E15440E6601603F2E1F838413672A081 
2018-07-16 14:47:20.769 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 010 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.769 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 011 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.769 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 012 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.769 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 013 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.769 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 014 Sign: plaintext: 0ADF060A1B08021A0608F8DFB2DA0522...2D125F59820D12080A021A0012021A00 
2018-07-16 14:47:20.769 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 015 Sign: digest: 5410F4209CCD1A087B41105BD228F74FEDA947105A2F89DD1D6CB946746917B1 
2018-07-16 14:47:20.771 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 016 Got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
2018-07-16 14:47:20.772 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 017 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.772 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 018 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.772 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 019 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-07-16 14:47:20.973 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 01a Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.973 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 01b Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.973 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 01c Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:20.973 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 01d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:20.973 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 01e Sign: plaintext: 0ADF060A1B08021A0608F8DFB2DA0522...176D1D022BCA12080A021A0012021A00 
2018-07-16 14:47:20.973 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 01f Sign: digest: A59E4533E2E097F2132A4D4A7E3D1AD17F0490773EFB6D29F19505AD0681BD4E 
2018-07-16 14:47:20.977 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 020 Received block: 0
2018-07-16 14:47:20.978 UTC [main] main -> INFO 021 Exiting.....
2018-07-16 14:47:21.112 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:21.112 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-16 14:47:21.113 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 003 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.4:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
2018-07-16 14:47:22.114 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 004 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.4:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
2018-07-16 14:47:23.819 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 005 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.4:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
Error: Error getting endorser client channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
Usage:
  peer channel join [flags]

Flags:
  -b, --blockpath string   Path to file containing genesis block

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server
```

---

It seems to me that the couchdb container died and caused the problem:

```
ubuntu@hyperledger ~/fabric-dev-servers % docker ps -a            
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
963b1857709b        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0      "peer node start"        24 minutes ago      Exited (2) 20 minutes ago                            peer0.org1.example.com
548bda25b4ae        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   25 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes               0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp   ca.org1.example.com
2e77b373d981        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0   "orderer"                25 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes               0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp   orderer.example.com
2f09d4b770eb        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   25 minutes ago      Exited (1) 24 minutes ago                            couchdb
```

---

Here are the logs of the died containers:

### fabric-couchdb:

```
ubuntu@hyperledger ~/fabric-dev-servers % docker logs 2f09d4b770eb 
****************************************************
WARNING: CouchDB is running in Admin Party mode.
         This will allow anyone with access to the
         CouchDB port to access your database. In
         Docker's default configuration, this is
         effectively any other container on the same
         system.
         Use "-e COUCHDB_USER=admin -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password"
         to set it in "docker run".
****************************************************
su-exec: /opt/couchdb/bin/couchdb: Permission denied
```

### fabric-peer:

```
ubuntu@hyperledger ~/fabric-dev-servers % docker logs 963b1857709b 
2018-07-16 14:47:04.906 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:04.906 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 002 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.1.0
 Go version: go1.9.2
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Experimental features: false
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.6
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger

2018-07-16 14:47:04.906 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 003 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-16 14:47:04.906 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 004 Initializing ledger mgmt
2018-07-16 14:47:04.906 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 005 Initializing ledger provider
2018-07-16 14:47:04.906 UTC [kvledger.util] CreateDirIfMissing -> DEBU 006 CreateDirIfMissing [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/ledgerProvider/]
2018-07-16 14:47:04.906 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 007 Before creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/ledgerProvider/] does not exist
2018-07-16 14:47:04.906 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 008 After creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/ledgerProvider/] exists
2018-07-16 14:47:04.986 UTC [kvledger.util] CreateDirIfMissing -> DEBU 009 CreateDirIfMissing [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/index/]
2018-07-16 14:47:04.986 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 00a Before creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/index/] does not exist
2018-07-16 14:47:04.987 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 00b After creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/index/] exists
2018-07-16 14:47:05.162 UTC [kvledger.util] CreateDirIfMissing -> DEBU 00c CreateDirIfMissing [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/pvtdataStore/]
2018-07-16 14:47:05.162 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 00d Before creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/pvtdataStore/] does not exist
2018-07-16 14:47:05.163 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 00e After creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/pvtdataStore/] exists
2018-07-16 14:47:05.254 UTC [statecouchdb] NewVersionedDBProvider -> DEBU 00f constructing CouchDB VersionedDBProvider
2018-07-16 14:47:05.254 UTC [couchdb] CreateConnectionDefinition -> DEBU 010 Entering CreateConnectionDefinition()
2018-07-16 14:47:05.255 UTC [couchdb] CreateConnectionDefinition -> DEBU 011 Created database configuration  URL=[http://couchdb:5984]
2018-07-16 14:47:05.255 UTC [couchdb] CreateConnectionDefinition -> DEBU 012 Exiting CreateConnectionDefinition()
2018-07-16 14:47:05.255 UTC [couchdb] VerifyCouchConfig -> DEBU 013 Entering VerifyCouchConfig()
2018-07-16 14:47:05.255 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 014 Entering handleRequest()  method=GET  url=http://couchdb:5984/
2018-07-16 14:47:05.255 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 015 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:05.257 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 016 Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:47:05.382 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 017 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:05.383 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 018 Retrying couchdb request in 250ms. Attempt:2  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:47:05.634 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 019 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:05.634 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 01a Retrying couchdb request in 500ms. Attempt:3  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:47:06.134 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 01b HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:06.135 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 01c Retrying couchdb request in 1s. Attempt:4  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:47:07.136 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 01d HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:07.137 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 01e Retrying couchdb request in 2s. Attempt:5  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:47:09.137 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 01f HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:09.138 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 020 Retrying couchdb request in 4s. Attempt:6  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:47:13.139 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 021 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:13.140 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 022 Retrying couchdb request in 8s. Attempt:7  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:47:21.141 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 023 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:21.141 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 024 Retrying couchdb request in 16s. Attempt:8  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:47:37.142 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 025 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:47:37.143 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 026 Retrying couchdb request in 32s. Attempt:9  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:48:09.144 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 027 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:48:09.146 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 028 Retrying couchdb request in 1m4s. Attempt:10  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:49:13.146 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 029 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  | 
2018-07-16 14:49:13.147 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 02a Retrying couchdb request in 2m8s. Attempt:11  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-16 14:51:21.148 UTC [couchdb] VerifyCouchConfig -> DEBU 02b Exiting VerifyCouchConfig()
panic: Error in instantiating ledger provider: Unable to connect to CouchDB, check the hostname and port: Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.initialize(0xc4201fdd70)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:66 +0x49c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.Initialize.func1()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:52 +0x2a
sync.(*Once).Do(0x16c57f0, 0xc4201c9660)
    /opt/go/src/sync/once.go:44 +0xbe
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.Initialize(0xc4201fdd70)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:51 +0x4d
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.serve(0x16c5708, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:117 +0x155
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.glob..func1(0x164ce80, 0x16c5708, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:87 +0x3f
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x164ce80, 0x16c5708, 0x0, 0x0, 0x164ce80, 0x16c5708)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:599 +0x3e8
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x164d4e0, 0x11, 0xc420282910, 0x5)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:689 +0x2fe
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x164d4e0, 0x19, 0xc420016035)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:648 +0x2b
main.main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:112 +0x5e1
```

---

I have tried adding `dns_search: .` in composer file, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this on a Cloud provider platform? The error suggests that the attempted (CouchDB) (exec su to start)  did not have authority to do so. This looks environmental in nature. Also how much Memory, is there enough disk space? Which version of Composer ?

Comment: We don't support running inside LXD and I must admit you have managed to get more running than I thought would be possible trying to run one container environment inside of another container environment. All I can suggest is that if you can't figure out the problem then try running it either on a bare metal system with ubuntu or a ubuntu setup on a hypervisor system such as virtualbox

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony I'm running Composer v0.19.12 on a local Machine with 16GB of RAM. I assigned ~60GB disk space to the LXD. Does the fabric-couchdb need access to `/opt/couchdb/bin/couchdb` of the ubuntu16.04?

Comment: @david_k It actually started very easy to run inside an LXD. I just used `lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 hyperledger -c security.nesting=true` to setup the ubuntu container.

Comment: Yep, but still doesn't mean we would try to support this environment. What does surprise me is that docker actually appears to work or at least perform some activities given it is a completely different type of container system trying to run inside a container system.

Comment: @david_k I understand and will set up a VM, thanks.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more. What you have shown though using LXD was really interesting, being able to do more than I would have expected. I wish I had more time to look at some of these other container technologies. LXD is definitely an interesting one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Now it is resolved. Run the command "docker network ls" to see list of all networks. Then inspect your network by "docker network inspect YOUR_NETWORK_NAME" to see if couchdb is part of the network. If CouchDB is not part of the network, inspect .yml file you used for running the containers. Especially, in .yml file, keep "networks" field of couchDB as the name of your present network.